# SAP Hybris based ECommerce platform

Tags: e-commerce, spree, sap-commerce-cloud

We're going to launch an online store and want to know if we should choose [Hybris](http://www.hybris.com/en/) or other platform (for ex. [Spree](https://spreecommerce.com/)). We plan to have ~3-5k customers in 3 years after release.

It should have all the standard features an online store has. Like payment systems integrations, responsive design, admin panel, reviews etc.
And some extra features like abandoned carts, gift cards, Elasticsearch (or similar for ex. Solr).

Also, it's crucial to be able to make deep customizations in the future: add new features, modify design etc.

Is Hybris suitable for these tasks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Hybris supports the desired features. The default indexation technology is SOLR. Also all kinds of customizations/integrations/features are possible but you will need a development team for them. Although, once properly made, the shop can be customized using only CMS components.

Some other Hybris features:

It is written in Java

Different cockpits/admin panels for different roles. (CMS Cockpit, Product Cockpit, General Admin..)

The question here is if you really need such an enterprise e-commerce system.  The licenses are not cheap and there are a lot of out of the box features, which you will probably not use.

If your goal is a basic shop with some common features and customizations, maybe Spree is a better solution. Here it all depends on your scaling plan.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Hristo! We'll think about it. What about the design? Does Hybris have some designs to choose from or we'd need designers/frontend developers attendance?

Comment: Hello, there is one default storefront theme and i haven't seen something like a theme library or so. Hybris is not a drag and drop platform so you have to develop your own designs.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris is acquired by `SAP` on `1st-Aug-2013` that's why called `SAP Hybris`. Its a platform for `E-Commerce`. Using `Hybris` one can do End-End development of `E-Commerce` application. This platform is developed using Java. It uses Ant as a build tool.

**Frameworks:** Spring Framework features / modules like Spring AOP, Spring MVC, Spring RestFul, Spring Security
 - caching, Persistance like (ZK, Hibernate, JPA etc), Search, Import / Export, Internationalization, Solr (For Indexing)

**FrontEnd:** JSF and other UI technology

**Databases:** You can use any database like Mysql, Oracle, SQL server, etc

**App Server:** You can use any Hybris Server, JBoss, IBM Webshere, Oracle BEA, SpringSource tc Server etc

**User Interfaces:** Product Cockpit, CMS Cockpit, Print Cockpit, Admin, HMC, Multi-Channel Cockpit

Using SAP Hybris, we can developed B2B, B2C

Answer (score 0):

SAP Hybris is the best for B2B and B2C business development. So you can just start working on your shop with SAP Hybris. If you are planning to built it with an external support, you can view the following link [SAP Hybris](https://www.egrovesys.com/sap-hybris/) to get clear idea.